# Why does attribute align="center" work in my html5 file?

Tags: html, alignment

I just started with html and wrote a small basic file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            A Page
        </title
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">
            A Header
        </h1>
        <p>
            Some content
        </p>
        <audio src="some-audio.mp3" controls>
            If this shows, somthing is not right.
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

By inserting `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta charset="UTF-8">` i wanted to make it a html5 file. To test this, I inserted the audio, which should not work with previous html versions.

But since the audio works and the file is html5, why does the `<h1 align="center">` still work?

Everywhere I search it always says that the align attribute is not supported by html5.

I will leave the file online until the question is solved: http://patriclay.de/testhtml5.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Doctype is used only to switch between [standards and quirks modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode).

Browsers support obsolete elements and attributes for the sake of backwards compatibility.

This is [explicitly mentioned in the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#tables-2) which says:

> The following rules are also expected to apply, as presentational hints:
>
> …
>
> ```
> p[align=center i], h1[align=center i], h2[align=center i], h3[align=center i],
> h4[align=center i], h5[align=center i], h6[align=center i] {
>   text-align: center;
> }
> ```

Do note, however, that [the spec also says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#non-conforming-features):

> The following attributes are obsolete (though the elements are still part of the language), and must not be used by authors:

Comment: A browser might support it today, but it might fail tomorrow.

Comment: @AndyG — Only if they change the spec (or a browser doesn't follow the spec)

Comment: *expected to apply* and *presentational hints* do not instil one with confidence ;). Best to avoid obsolete elements and attributes.

Comment: I understand, thank you. :)